# Does an image get downloaded N times on an HTML page if it's being used N times?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an image

```html
<img src="~/Images/User_small.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
```

that is being used in about 25 places on my page.

Does that mean that it has to fetch it 25 times from my filesystem, or does it know to get it once then reuse it again if the remaining page asks for it?

If it does fetch more then once, can I somehow save it/cache it so that it doesn't have to get called 25+ times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the browser will cache it and reuse it, no worries.
This also applies if the image is specified in a css file.

If you visit another page(on the same server), that also uses that image(without closing the browser), it will still be fetched from cache.
It all depends on the url being the same.

Depending on your cache settings, it might also remember the image next time you visit the page.